# Need help with inductive proof of Binomial Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, notation, induction, binomial-theorem

I'm new to math and trying to learn about the Binomial Theorem, by following this [tutorial](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/binomial_thm/).
I got stuck trying to read the [Induction Proof](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/binomial_thm/induction.html).

They give an example of using the Sum notation:

$$ (x + y)^1 = {1 \choose 0} x^{1-0}  y^0  +  {1 \choose 1} x^{1-1}  y^1  = \sum^{1}_{k=0} {n \choose k} x^{n-k}y^k.$$

If I simplify the terms in the middle part, I get: $ x^{1-0} y^0 + x^{1-1} y^1 = x + y $ , which is what I expected from $ (x+y)^1 $ .

However if I try to extend that to $ (x+y)^2 $ :

$$ (x + y)^2 = {2 \choose 0} x^{2-0}  y^0  +  {2 \choose 1} x^{2-1}  y^1  +   {2 \choose 2} x^{2-2}  y^2.  $$

And then simplify the terms, I get: $ x^{2-0}  y^0  +  x^{2-1}  y^1  +  x^{2-2}  y^2  = x^2 + xy + y^2 $ .  But there is only one $xy$ whereas I expected to get $2xy$ . . .  as in $ (x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 $ .

Why is there only $xy$ instead of $2xy$ , am I missing something here ?

Comment: You are forgetting to multiply the binomial coefficients.

Comment: ${2 \choose 1}=2$

Comment: Thanks for that  @FoobazJohn . I thought I could just ignore those binomial coefficients, that they were just part of the Summation notation. Now I know what they are :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients given by the formula are correct; for instance, ${2}\choose{1}$$=2$, so it gives you $x^2+2xy+y^2$. In general, 
${n}\choose{k} $$=$
$$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$
e.g. ${2}\choose{1}$$=$
$$\frac{2!}{1!\cdot1!} = \frac{2}{1} = 2$$

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, it makes sense now.